# How do I get the HTTP resp code on a browserField request?

Tags: blackberry, facebook

In my  blackberry app, it shares news through a facebook sharing url on browserfield.
If I check it on my facebook, It has successfully shared.

I want to know How I can get the HTTP response code from the browser field, and also  How to close the browserfield after sharing the news.

Please Help.

Comment: I don't have the answer right away, but have you tried looking at how the BB Facebook SDK handles these situations?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) to access the URL, instead of using a [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html)?   The method 'getResponseCode()' on HttpConnection will return what you want.